# Using Cast on Left Join to Change VARCHAR to DECIMAL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, decimal, varchar, sqldatatypes

I need to join a table using a user defined column (UDF1) that contains text data and account numbers to another table on account numbers (LDACCT). The account numbers should be formatted as decimal(16,0), but the column UDF1 has text data in it (as well as account numbers) because UDF1 is also used for purposes other than to house account numbers (not my design). My current join isn't working:

```
left outer join dbo.tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions as ll2
   on  CAST(uf.UDF1 as decimal(16, 0)) = ll2.LDACCT
```

I'm getting the dreaded: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric`, and I can't seem to modify the join to resolve the error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have to use CAST in a JOIN condition it indicates your database is poorly designed. Fix that instead!

Comment: what about: ... on CAST(uf.UDF1 as varchar(255)) = cast(ll2.LDACCT as varchar(255)) ??

Comment: @jarlh maybe the op doesn't have the permissions to do that

Comment: jarlh - I would if I could - as Lamak guessed! Let me give Eray's idea a try - thanks for the input all!

Comment: Eray's "flipping the script" solution works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @Craig you are welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the "on" part as:

```
on CAST(uf.UDF1 as varchar(255)) = cast(ll2.LDACCT as varchar(255))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of your rows in `uf` has something in it that can't be cast to a `decimal`. Try

```
select
    *
  from uf
 where left(uf.UDF1,1) not in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

Depending on whether you want to ignore that row, you can either try to exclude that row through other criteria, or you can turn the join around, casting the other side to a string:

```
...
left outer join dbo.tbl_Loan_Legal_Descriptions as ll2
   on  uf.UDF1 = cast(varchar,ll2.LDACCT)
```

If you try that, you might need to strip leading zeroes from `uf.UDF1`, but as you did not show us any representative data from the tables, all we can do here is just guess or caution about it.

Comment: Corlon, you're second suggestion is similar to Eray's that worked perfectly.  The varchar values that aren't account numbers in UDF1 vary but they're often a mix of text and numbers but none have leading 0s.  Thanks!